# How should I use bitmaps?

Tags: android, bitmap

I have a serious problem with the memory usage for `bitmaps` and if it's `ViewPager` is more critical. Analyzing  the Android Studio's Memory monitor, the memory usage increments signigficantly. I have used libraries to load images without success, I have tried to recycle them but it's very risky because of Android may crash at any time.

Some idea? :( The point is that if that issue isn't controlled, the application may crash with the annoying `java.lang.memoryOutError`.

Comment: You need to rescale your bitmaps, it sounds like you are trying to load a bunch of HD images when you could likely scale them down to something lower in resolution.

Comment: Have you seen this?  http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: @zgc7009 I have rescaled the images, nevertheless it's a short-term solution. The classic problem view design vs performance.

Comment: Nice information @BojanKseneman. Thank you!

Comment: Did you scale the image as suggested in the `Load a Scaled Down Version into Memory` of the link provided by @BojanKseneman ? That should be a reasonable solution unless you are managing a good number of images at once. Not that it is THE solution, but when I have run into this issue in the past that scaling method has solved it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try caching the Bitmaps in a [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) which would automatically recycle bitmaps when you are reaching your memory limit. If that does not help, you can request for a larger heap size for your app by including `android:largeHeap="true"` in the `application` tag in your Android Manifest file. Also to stop the app from crashing due to insufficient memory, you should try and listen to the `onLowMemory()` method within your application and activity classes, and try to clear/recycle as much data as you can in that method.

Comment: Interesting :). Man, do you have a example? It would really be great :D

Comment: You can check out the sample code for using the LRUCache from Android's documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) and from [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html) sample app. As for what to do when the `onLowMemory()` method is called depends on exactly what is consuming memory in your app. You will have to quickly clear that data from memory. You can also try storing images to a disk cache.